# C# Convert HTML/XML to Hexadecimal Code Points

Tags: c#, algorithm, hex, converters

I am looking for a way to convert HTML/XML code to Hexadecimal Code Points in C#.

Example: `&#55357;&#56835;` to `1F603`

This **[tool](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)** does exactly what I'm looking for but it is written in JavaScript.

What's the best way to handle such conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```css
                        string code1 = "&#55357";
                        string code2 = "&#56835";
                        ulong numbericCode1 = ulong.Parse(code1.Substring(2));
                        ulong numbericCode2 = ulong.Parse(code2.Substring(2));

                        string hexCode = (numbericCode1 + numbericCode2).ToString("x5");​
```

Comment: The output does not match the proper conversion. Also, this method will not properly convert strings with more than two HTML codes.

Comment: The code was just an example of parsing the two inputs.  I have no idea where the 1F603 is coming from.  I thought the number 1F603 was a typo.  I tried different math operation to get 1F603 and was not successful.

Comment: It is not a typo. `&#55357;&#56835;` is equivalent to a smiley character `` which is `1F603` in hex code points. Based on that conversion site, the input converts XML to a char, then decimal to hex and finally that result to code points. `.ToString("X")` successfully converts one number adding them will not give the correct result.